# Getting User Input to HashMap as Keys and Printing Its Respective Values in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am beginner to Java. I have been doing this exercise on HashMap. First, I need to input key:value pairs as user inputs in given format of John 1234, Sam 789 and to create HashMap. Then, I need to input a Name and check whether it is in created HashMap and if it is, then prints its respective value in a given format of John=1234. But, whatever Name I input, I get else message, as mentioned in following code. Can anybody please tell me how I need to develop following code to get the intended output? Thank you.

```
    public static void main (String [] arg){ 
    HashMap<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N = obj.nextInt();
    obj.nextLine();

    while (N > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String name = obj.findInLine("\\D+ ");
            int contact = obj.nextInt();
            obj.nextLine();
            phonebook.put(name, contact);
        }   
        String search = obj.nextLine();
            if (phonebook.containsKey(search))
            {
                Integer a = phonebook.get(search);
                System.out.println(search+"="+a);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not Found");
            }   
        }
        N--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: After entering 3 key:value pairs, again I enter a name (String search). But, for any entered name (even existing in created HashMap) I get the else output, which is "Not Found"

Comment: I gave answer for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go . I slightly modified you solution to make it work!
You don't need a for loop inside the while loop. Only while loop is fine.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N = obj.nextInt();
    obj.nextLine();

    while (N-- > 0) {

        String name = obj.findInLine("\\D+");
        name =name.trim();
        int contact = obj.nextInt();
        obj.nextLine();
        phonebook.put(name, contact);
    }
    System.out.println(phonebook);

    // obj.nextLine();

    String search = obj.nextLine();

    if (phonebook.containsKey(search)) {
        Integer a = phonebook.get(search);
        System.out.println(search + "=" + a);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.I tried your suggestion, but still I get the Not found for any String search input.

Comment: I added the screenshot also to the answer that it is working fine!

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. But the thing is, I am supposed enter key:value pairs of HashMap in a single line according to a given format of John 1234. (Space between) For this, I have used String name = obj.findInLine("\\D+ ") not String name = obj.nextLine();. Your answer is compatible with nextLine() but not with findinLine. I got the results of your screenshot for obj.nextLine(). But I need to use obj.findInLine("\\D+ "). Could you please help me out there?

Comment: Updated the answer , I could see the space in the name being added. So trimmed the space before adding into the map, it should work now!

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much for your response. Highly appreciate..

Comment: Good to know. Hope you wont mind upvoting it. Happy Learning!